# Is the deterministic block universe compatible with human free will?

Tags: special-relativity, determinism

Is Einstein's deterministic block universe compatible with human free will?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about philosophy and not physics.

Comment: Since it seems likely we live in a deterministic universe and since it's obvious we have free will, I'm going to go with "yes, they're compatible".

Comment: A precise definition of "free will" would be required before any sensible answer can be given. There are multiple possible such definitions: which one does the OP intend?

Comment: Since there is no main stream physics theory of free will, this is not possible to answer with main stream physics. Opinion will be a large part of any answer. So in spite of it being an interesting question, I am voting to close it.

Comment: This question could use some additional details, but regardless would make more sense to ask on [philosophy.se] than here.